# Derivative of matrix exponential at $0$

Tags: matrices, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

I have to show that the derivative of 'the matrix exponential' $exp: \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}\mapsto\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ at the zero matrix $0$ is $id_{C^{n\times n}}$, i.e. $exp(0)=id$. The above map isn't given explicitly, so maybe someone can tell me what it does to a matrix $A$?
I think the obvious guess would be $$A\mapsto e^A:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}$$, but I wouldn't know how to find the derivation of such a map since there is no variable.

So far I tried considering $$Ax\mapsto e^Ax:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(Ax)^k}{k!}$$
instead, which is a map $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ I suppose.

As derivative I get $Ax\mapsto Ae^{Ax}$, which gives the identity for $x=0$, but $0$ for $A=0$.

Can somebody tell me what I got wrong, and how it is true that $exp(0)=id$?

Comment: $A$ is the variabile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$e^A$ is indeed $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}$. To find the derivative at the zero matrix, let $B$ be an arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix which is unit in some norm, let $\epsilon>0$ be a small number, and consider

$$e^{\epsilon B}-e^0=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^k B^k}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{0^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^k B^k}{k!}.$$

(Here by definition $A^0=I$ for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$, including the zero matrix.) Any idea what to do now? (Hint: what is the relative size of the terms?)

Comment: Note: we're using the [Frechet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) here

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The space is finite dimensional, the distinction between different sorts of derivatives doesn't matter. (Or perhaps I misunderstood the point of your comment?)

Comment: No, I'm at a loss, sorry. What does $e^{\epsilon B}-e^0$ have to do with the derivative?

Comment: @see By definition, for any given norm on $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, the derivative of $e^A$ at $0$ is a linear map $L : \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ such that for any unit matrix $B$, $e^{\epsilon B}-e^0=\epsilon L(B) + o(\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. Because the space is finite dimensional, $L$ turns out to not depend on the norm that we picked. So what you're looking for is basically the "order $\epsilon^1$ terms" in $e^{\epsilon B}-\epsilon^0$. There is just one of those...

Comment: What definition of derivative is that? I think I need to catch up on this a little since I never saw this definition before.

Comment: @see What definition are you using? I guarantee that it is equivalent to this one, but it may take some work to prove that.

Comment: To be honest I only know the usual definition from calculus, I didn't have to find the derivation of a matrix-valued function before. I think I have to look this up before I continue with the exercise.

Comment: @see This definition is not so different from the calculus definition. The reason that there must be some difference is that you can't divide by a vector. So instead you perturb from your starting point going a small distance in some *direction* and divide by the *distance* that you went. So here that would be $\frac{e^{\epsilon B}-e^0}{\epsilon}$. Then you send $\epsilon\to 0$. This result depends on the direction $B$ that you went in, but (assuming your function is differentiable in the first place) this dependence is linear. We call the derivative this linear map that $B$ gets plugged into.

Comment: @see You probably used essentially the same idea when you looked at gradients in multivariable calculus. The difference is that the derivative of a scalar valued function $f$ of a vector variable $x$ at a point $x_0$ is not really $\nabla f(x_0)$ but rather the map $y \mapsto \nabla f(x_0) \cdot y$, where $\cdot$ is the dot product. Similarly the derivative of a vector valued function of a vector variable is $y \mapsto J(x_0) y$ where $J$ is the Jacobian and the multiplication is ordinary matrix multiplication.

Comment: So does that mean that since $\frac{e^{\epsilon B}-e^0}{\epsilon}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon^{k-1}B^k}{k!}\rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{0^k}{k!}=e^0=id$ for $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ one has $dexp(0)=id$?

Comment: @see Actually, I checked again; your conclusion is correct but your rationale is wrong. You have $\frac{e^{\epsilon B}-e^0}{\epsilon} \to B$. Thus given $B$, the derivative spits $B$ back out at you. Thus the derivative is the identity.

Comment: But for $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, I have $\epsilon^{k-1}B^k\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @see When $k=1$, $\epsilon^{k-1}=1$.

Comment: Oh I see it now. And $e^0=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{0^k}{k!}=0^0+0=id$ because by definition $A^0=id$ for any $A$, including $0$. Ok.

Comment: @Ian the point is that this wikipedia page is the one with the nicest explanation of the derivative, as it applies to your answer.

Comment: One last question though. Is it really necessary that $B$ is unit in some norm? I don't see where we use this and wouldn't this mean that our expression only gives back $B$ for $B$ with this property, i.e. is the identity only for those matrices which are units?

Comment: @see The result doesn't depend on the norm (because the space is finite dimensional, as it turns out), but $B$ does need to be unit in whatever norm we're talking about. Otherwise $\epsilon$ alone is not the "absolute scale of bigness" of $\epsilon B$, if that makes sense. In multivariable calculus this is the analogy of taking the dot product of the gradient with a *unit* vector rather than an arbitrary vector to compute a directional derivative.